# How to format as XFS version 4?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, xfs

[Apparently](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/XFS-USB-key-not-recognized/m-p/1631525/highlight/true#M103481), my router uses a legacy Linux kernel and can't read / write to XFS5 despite the [support page](https://kb.netgear.com/24059/What-are-the-USB-drive-requirements-for-my-Nighthawk-router) claiming it has full read-write compatibility with XFS.

I currently use Ubuntu 18.10, and I tried to search a bit around GParted, GNOME Disks and [mkfs.xfs' man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.xfs), but there's no mention of XFS4.

So, my question is : How can I format a drive to XFS4?

Comment: I also need this, but not specifically with ubuntu.  I have an older machine that cannot be upgraded that need XFS 4 and not 5.